# Python: Is there a thread safe way to know if lock.acquire() has blocked (and continue blocking)?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, locking

I'm writing an API library for my REST service. At some point, access token will need to be renewed. I'm trying to implement a thread-safe way to do it so only one renew request is sent, even though multiple threads may want to renew it at the same time.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```py
import requests

class Api():
    def _renew(self):
        # send a request which renews token in self._headers

    def do_something(self, url, params=None):
        r = requests(url, params=params, headers=self._headers)
        if r.status_code == 401 and r.json()['error'] == 'Token expired':
             # renew the access token
             self._renew()
             # repeat request with updated headers
             r = requests(url, params=params, headers=self._headers)
        return r.json()
```

I need to know if a current renew request is in progress. My idea was to write the renew function like this:

```
def _renew(self):
    lock.acquire()
    # i want to check here if the lock.acquire() call blocked
    # the thread and return immediately if it has
    try:
        # send a request to renew token header in self._headers
    finally:
        lock.release()
```

I want other threads which may call `do_something()` (and subsequently `_renew()`) method  to wait until the first really renews the tokens and make others use it's result.

How can I tell if my `lock.acquire()` call was blocking or not?

Checking the result of  `lock.locked()` before calling `acquire()` is not thread-safe and sometimes more than one thread send renew request to the server.

Comment: I think you summed it up correctly. Let me rephrase your last sentence to see if we think the same: After the job is done, it should behave the same. The first thread to call _renew() should take the job, the rest should wait until the first finishes and return without doing the job. I have tested my version of the code (the one from the gist) which is really similar to yours and it seems like it works correctly. Where do you think is a potential problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you correctly. You mean that second wave of renewing wouldn't do anything? I have tested that and it worked... Maybe a better protection would be to move `event.clear()` immediately after `event.set()`?

Comment: That would help, but not solve the problem: A thread arriving between `event.clear()` and `lock.release()` could potentially wait for a `event.set()` that is not guaranteed to follow.

Comment: Please check my updated [gist](https://gist.github.com/jeremija/7ac95ed5e864888b1f40). I added `sleep()` between each statement to easily start threads between statements. The only problem is if `_renew()` is called between `lock.release()` and `event.clear()` - `i` will be increased again. But IRL it won't matter if `_renew()` is called just before or after `event.clear()`. If I want to avoid these kind of renews, I have to keep track when did the first request start and if I get `Token expired`, I should compare that start time to the times of last `_header` update.

Comment: I have updated the answer to fulfill thread-safety (afaik)

Comment: Thank you very much for this! This is much better! The code is more readable, and it's much easier to see what's really going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `lock.acquire(False)` for a nonblocking call and use the return value to determine if a lock has been acquired. This would look like this:

```
def _renew(self):
    # calling when the lock is already acquired
    # will not block and return False
    if not lock.acquire(False):
        event.wait()
        return
    # else we acquired the lock 
    event.clear()
    try:
        # send a request to renew token header in self._headers
    finally:
        event.set()
        lock.release()
```

See [the threading-docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Lock.acquire) for python.

Another approach is to wrap the token in another class:

```
from threading import Event, RLock

class Token:
    _internal = RLock()
    _marker = False
    def __init__(self):
        # TODO set header
        self._header = None

    def _renew(self):
        # TODO refresh the header
        pass

    def get(self):
        with self._internal:
            if self._marker:
                self._renew()
                self._marker = False
            return self._header

    # Marks the header to be refreshed at the next get()
    def set_renew(self):
        with self._internal:
            self._marker = True
```

This has several advantages. First of all the token is responsible for itself. In the best possible environment it would only refresh itself whenever needed and NOT get refreshed by other classes. This should be decided in `Token#get(self)`. This also solves thread-safety by wrapping all get-calls into a lock, preventing unwanted modifications.

Comment: Thanks, I know about that, but I want the call to block until the first thread finishes. All the other threads should wait and then use the modified `self._headers` that the first thread set.

Comment: Thanks, I think `threading.Event` might be what I'm looking for. I'm reading the docs :)

Comment: Oops I didn't notice your edit before I posted that gist. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have edited the answer. Wrapping the token into his own class is a better desing imo, consider it. You would of course have to replace all `._header` with tokens and get them with `self._header.get()`. If the token is responsible for itself you could also define `Token.__get__(self, obj, type)` as an alias to Token.get(self), you won't have to call `_header.get` explicitly (won't work if you don't have a descriptor class around Token)